# MariaDB Galera + Remote Backup

Tags: backup, mariadb, remote

I'm using CentOS 8 and I have a MariaDB 10.5.4 Galera set up with three nodes. Now, I want it to create a backup to my central server from time to time. I'm thinking of `mysqldump` but restoration would take a lot of time and `mariabackup` does not support remote backups (I think). So I'm thinking of creating a Master-Slave to from my galera cluster setup to a stand-alone setup on my central server then I run `mariabackup` from there like this:

[image]

For now my current set up is that I had my third node act as a backup for HAProxy and it is where `mariabackup` is currently running (see image and remove central server). But my boss wanted me to store backup on central and let central do the backup instead of the database server.

Are there any simple alternative? I'm thinking of following [this guide](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mariadb/master-slave-replication-galera-cluster), but it's a bit outdated and I'm not sure if it would work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Central backups occurring on a replica is a decent strategy.

The guide on quick glance looks ok. Ensure that your `server-id` is unique. Per [mariadb galera guidance](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/using-mariadb-replication-with-mariadb-galera-cluster-using-mariadb-replica/#setting-server_id-on-cluster-nodes) galera cluster members shoudl have the same `server-id` in most scenarios.. Its unclear why `binlog-format=mixed` when galera requires `row` so I'd just keep row.

'log-slave-updates' is the critical thing of the master node but for consistency its easy enough to have this on all galera nodes in case you need to change master at some point.

Like all backups consider the process that a restoration would take and business requirements on MTTR (mean time to recover). And test the restoration process when you've got backup to see it works and how long it takes.

Comment: So the galera nodes can have the same `server_id` of 01? I'll give this a try, thanks!

Comment: server id is a numeric so leading 0 has no effect. Recommend reading [galera server id](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/using-mariadb-replication-with-mariadb-galera-cluster-using-mariadb-replica/#setting-server_id-on-cluster-nodes) official docs like I should of before writing this answer.

Comment: Hello, kinda came up with this problem just now, is it possible to set up multiple master to a single slave, like one master contains the dev database and the other contains production database then they all send data to my central server, since I cant have 2 instances on of mariadb on my server. And another server would be costly.

Comment: new problems are for new questions, however look at [Multi-Source Replication](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/multi-source-replication/) and create new question if you have troubles/need further clarification. Mark this answer as correct if you are happy with it.

Comment: Well, I'm just thinking far ahead of my current tasks, anyway what does this mean **`gitd_domain_id` should be set to a different value on all nodes** ? does this mean that one of my nodes should be 1, the other is 2, then the other is 3?

Comment: [gtid_domain_id](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/using-mariadb-replication-with-mariadb-galera-cluster-configuring-mariadb-r/#configuring-wsrep-gtid-mode) needs to be the same on all cluster members. clarified server-id in answer. A same `server-id` on all nodes is the usual case. The alternate case doesn't apply to your scenario